# Configuration for projects in subdirectory

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle multi-project build that looks like this:

```
rootProject
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    shared/
        SharedLib
        SharedLib2
    plugins/
        FirstPlugin
        SecondPlugin
```

I'd like to add all projects in the directory `shared` as dependencies to all projects in `plugins`.

More generally speaking: **How do I configure subprojects by directory?**

---

Contents of settings.gradle:

```
include 'plugins:FirstPlugin', 'plugins:SecondPlugin', 'shared:SharedLib', 'shared:SharedLib2'
```

Contents of build.gradle:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = "2.1" }

allprojects{ apply plugin:"java" }
subprojects {
    group = "eu.test.myGroup"
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { testCompile "junit:junit:4.11" }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to build.gradle does what I wanted to achieve:

```
// Define what's a plugin and what's a shared library by directory paths.
// Ignore empty projects
def plugins = subprojects.findAll{ it.path.contains("plugins") && hasSrc(it) }
def sharedLibs = subprojects.findAll{ it.path.contains("shared") && hasSrc(it)}

/** Checks whether a project has a source directory */
def hasSrc(proj){
    return new File(proj.projectDir, "src").exists()
}

// Configure the plugins to depend on the shared libraries at compile time
configure(plugins) { dependencies { sharedLibs.each{compile it} } }
```